# MVC calling controller from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got an MVC view that is successfully calling a controller.  In the controller, I call a stored procedure (using entity framework) and get some results.  That part of it all works fine.  But, I'm unable to get my results back from my javascript.  When I have it as an ActionResult, all is fine, I just can't seem to get to the result.  When I try to change it to a JsonResult, I keep getting an "Internal Server" error, so I'm not sure which way to go.  Any pointers would help (I'm not a great javascript/jquery developer).

My javascript:

```
         var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: varurl,
            data: { text: tempField, letterId: "2" },
            cache: false,
            success: function (results) { alert(results) }
        })
        .done(function (result) {
            $('#content').empty();
            $('#content').html(result);
            $('#content').html(result);
        })
        .error(function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        });
        //letterArea.value = letterArea.value + title[0] + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + title[1] + "\r\n" + "\r\n";
        letterArea.value = "Hello";
    }
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult ResolveText(string text, string letterId)
    {
        using (LMNEntities db = new LMNEntities())
        {
            var results = db.ResolveFieldsForLetter(Convert.ToInt32(letterId),text);
            return View(results);
        }


    }
```

Comment: if you are returning json then add responseType:json to your ajax config object and try again

Comment: I've tried making it json and then I just get "internal server error".  Perhaps I'm doing that wrong.  I set my controller to return JsonResult,, my return to be "Json(results)" and a datatype on my ajax call to be json.  Do I need to do some type of conversion in my controller for that?

Comment: In your ResolveText.cshtml, do you have a viewmodel set that matches the return of your sproc method?

Comment: that might be part of my problem.  But, then I might have an Entity Framework question.  All other stored procedures that I have create a "Complex Type", which is the Result from the stored procedure.  This one doesn't seem to have one.  It works fine in my method because I just return to a "C# var" (rather than instantiate a "new" before)....Stored procedure just returns a string...let me try to resolve that...

Comment: It may be a good idea to create some view models (specifically used in views) and maybe have two constructors, one that takes no args and 1 that takes in your complex type and sets property values.

Comment: Getting the right model on the view was exactly what I needed.  That did it!  Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, use `data: { text: tempField, letterId: 2 }` and change the method to `public ActionResult ResolveText(string text, int letterId)` and delete the unnecessary `Convert.ToInt32(letterId)` It should also be `return PartialView(results);`